# Increment a text file name in java

Tags: java, int, increment

Im trying to increment a text file name so that all text files created will have a unique name and will be in ascending order.  Here is the code I've got so far. I hope you can  understand the logic of what I am attempting here. The problem is either that the program is locking up or this code does nothing. Thanks.

increase is a global int of 0

```
    String name = String.valueOf(increase);
    File file = new File("E:\\" + name + ".txt");

    while(file.exists()){
         increase++;


    if(!file.exists()) {

        try {

            String content = textfile.toString();
            file.createNewFile();

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content);
            bw.close();

            System.out.println("Done");

            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: first the lockup if the file exists it will go into the while but not the if and infinite loop as file is never reassigned.. second the doing nothing the file doesnt go into the while and then never even gets to the if and ends

Comment: Hi. Sorry but I dont understand what you mean. Could you explain it another way or write what should be done in code format? Thank you clancer.

Comment: added an answer with the code

Comment: You can express the filename as `"E:/" + name`, Java will translate `/` to `\\` on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to explain my comment with code

```
String name = String.valueOf(increase);
File file = new File("E:\\" + name + ".txt");

while(file.exists()){
     increase++;
     // reassign file this while will terminate when #.txt doesnt exist
     name = String.valueOf(increase);
     file = new File("E:\\" + name + ".txt");
} // the while should end here
// then we check again that #.txt doesnt exist and try to create it
if(!file.exists()) {

try {

    String content = textfile.toString();
    file.createNewFile();

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write(content);
    bw.close();

    System.out.println("Done");

}catch (IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
// you had a extra close bracket here causing the issue
}
// this program will now create a new text file each time its run in ascending order
```

Comment: Thank you clancer. Its nice to see my thought process wasn't a million miles off the mark. This works perfectly in my program now. I can see from the comments that file file also needs to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

While you update your int variable `increase`, you don't change your `File file`. That's why you end in an infinite loop.

Comment: Also `name` isn't automatically changed.

Answer (score 1):

The code below I wrote for my project requirement which works with all/without extensions. Hope that helps!

```
public static File getValidFile(String filePath) {
    File file = new File(filePath);

    if (!file.exists()) {
        return file;
    } else {
        int extAt = filePath.lastIndexOf('.');
        String filePart = filePath;
        String ext = "";

        if(extAt > 0) { //If file is without extension
            filePart = filePath.substring(0, extAt);
            ext = filePath.substring(extAt);
        }

        if (filePart.endsWith(")")) {
            try {
                int countStarts = filePart.lastIndexOf('(');
                int countEnds = filePart.lastIndexOf(')');
                int count = Integer.valueOf(filePart.substring(countStarts + 1, countEnds));

                filePath = filePart.substring(0, countStarts + 1) + ++count + ")" + ext;
            } catch (NumberFormatException | StringIndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
                filePath = filePart + "(1)" + ext;
            }
        } else {
            filePath = filePart + "(1)" + ext;
        }
        return getValidFile(filePath);
    }
}
```